# python code speed up nested for loops with two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, performance, vectorization, nested-for-loop

ServicePop has x, y coordinate and I want to add a square number(gid).
I made a nested for loop to assign a square number but ServicePop is so huge then it takes several hours.
Is there a faster and efficient way to do it?
When I search at Google they say using apply of dataframe or vectorization will help but I could not alter my code to use such an improvement.
I need your help, please.

```
import pandas
import datetime
TotPopCenter = pandas.read_csv('TotalPopulationCurrentCenterShapeCoordinate_UTF8.csv', encoding='euckr')
ServicePop = pandas.read_csv('202101_Final.csv', encoding='euckr')
ServicePop.insert(9,'gid','')
Service_gid = ['' for _ in range(len(ServicePop))]
for j in range(len(ServicePop)):
    for i in range(len(TotPopCenter)):
        if (ServicePop['X_COORD'][j] >= TotPopCenter['xcoord'][i]-125) and \
           (ServicePop['X_COORD'][j] < TotPopCenter['xcoord'][i]+125) and \
           (ServicePop['Y_COORD'][j] >= TotPopCenter['ycoord'][i]-125) and \
           (ServicePop['Y_COORD'][j] < TotPopCenter['ycoord'][i]+125):
           Service_gid[j] = TotPopCenter['gid'][I]
ServicePop['gid'] = Service_gid
```

TotPopCenter
gid         lbl val xcoord  ycoord
0   LM87ab60ba  NaN NaN 1087375 1760625
ServicePop
STD_YMD     X_COORD       Y_COORD       HCODE   WKDY_CD TIME    HPOP    WPOP    VPOP
0   2021-01-01  1.087484e+06  1.760579e+06  2207061 FRI     0       27.97   0.82    7.24

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to optimize the nested loop specifically, you might want to use `itertools.product`, using:

```py
import itertools
for j, i in itertools.product(range(len(ServicePop)), range(len(TotPopCenter))):
```

rather than:

```py
for j in range(len(ServicePop)):
    for i in range(len(TotPopCenter)):
```